# Unable to start new activity involving Firebase

Tags: android

I am building an app that has a charity and restaurant. They register themselves and then proceed using Firebase for database handling. When I register charity register charity should open but it shows error. Logcat and register charity file attached.

## activity register charity

```
package com.example.aayu.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

/**
 * Created by AAYU on 30-May-17.
 */

public class regc extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reg_c);




    final DatabaseReference rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReferenceFromUrl("https://myapplication-6e0b9.firebaseio.com/charity");

    final EditText mname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cname);
    final EditText madd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadd);
    final EditText mcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ccity);
    final EditText mstate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cstate);
    final EditText mpin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cpin);



    final Button mnext= (Button) findViewById(R.id.cnext);

      mnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view){
              String name = mname.getText().toString();
              String add = madd.getText().toString();
              String city = mcity.getText().toString();
              String state = mstate.getText().toString();
              String pin = mpin.getText().toString();

              DatabaseReference childref = rootref.child("Charity Name");
              childref.setValue(name);
              childref = rootref.child("Address");
              childref.setValue(add);
              childref = rootref.child("City");
              childref.setValue(city);
              childref = rootref.child("State");
              childref.setValue(state);
              childref = rootref.child("Pincode");
              childref.setValue(pin);
          }
      });



    //setContentView(R.layout.reg2_c);

    final EditText memail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cemail);
    final EditText mph = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cph);
    final EditText muname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuname);
    final EditText  mpwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cpwd);


    final Button mreg=(Button) findViewById(R.id.creg);

    mreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String email = memail.getText().toString();
            String ph = mph.getText().toString();
            String uname = muname.getText().toString();
            String pwd = mpwd.getText().toString();

            DatabaseReference childref = rootref.child("Email Id");
            childref.setValue(email);
            childref = rootref.child("Phone No");
            childref.setValue(ph);
            childref = rootref.child("Username");
            childref.setValue(uname);
            childref = rootref.child("Password");
            childref.setValue(pwd);

            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Registration done successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });


       // Intent loginc = new Intent(this, loginc.class);
       // startActivity(loginc);


}
}
```

## logcat

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11011000 but found 9877470
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 32230643
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aayu.myapplication/com.example.aayu.myapplication.regc}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                     at com.example.aayu.myapplication.regc.onCreate(regc.java:76)
                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.aayu.myapplication, PID: 9023
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aayu.myapplication/com.example.aayu.myapplication.regc}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.aayu.myapplication.regc.onCreate(regc.java:76)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
Application terminated.
```

## reg_c.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:id="@+id/cname"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Charity Home Name"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

<Button
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cnext"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:elevation="21dp"
    android:onClick="next" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/cadd"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cname"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cname"
    android:hint="Address "
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/ccity"
    android:hint="City"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cadd"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cadd" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/cstate"
    android:hint="State"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ccity"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ccity" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:id="@+id/cpin"
    android:hint="Pincode"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cstate"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cstate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## layout for reg_c.xml

[image: layout for reg_c.xml]

Comment: Can you please post "reg_c.xml" file here? The issue is that your Activity is unable to find the buttons from your layout file. Please post the file mentioned above here. So I can help you find the issue.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @ZohaibHassan added the file.Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @halfer sorry for this time will surely keep in mind for the next time.Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
final Button mreg=(Button) findViewById(R.id.creg);

mreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String email = memail.getText().toString();
        String ph = mph.getText().toString();
        String uname = muname.getText().toString();
        String pwd = mpwd.getText().toString();

        DatabaseReference childref = rootref.child("Email Id");
        childref.setValue(email);
        childref = rootref.child("Phone No");
        childref.setValue(ph);
        childref = rootref.child("Username");
        childref.setValue(uname);
        childref = rootref.child("Password");
        childref.setValue(pwd);

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Registration done successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });
```

You don't have any button with this id in your XML file but you are trying to access it in your Activity. That is causing Null Pointer Exception.

You have two solution:

1. If you need this button then add a button with the id "creg" in your XML file.

   **OR**
2. If you don't need that button then remove the code given above from your Activity.